What is the shortest path for this graph using Dijkstra's algorithm?
I'm stuck trying to understand how to use the Dijkstra's algorithm in this graph. I need to find the shortest path between "a" and "z", but I get stuck in the node "e" where you need to visit "b" or "z", "b" is the shortest path if we sum the weights but I know that will lead me to a longer path, I'm not sure how to proceed. Hope you can enlighten me this out with a step-by-step guide.
Graph

Welcome to MSE. More people will read (and try to answer) your question if they don't have to click on links. Where possible, please try to embed any pictures into your questions.

It is not clear to me whether you are trying to find the path of least length or the path of least weight. They are often not the same thing.

@RedFive I don't have enough reputation to embed any pictures, don't blame me on that.
GerryMyerson, about the path, I mean the path of least weight, I thought that was implicit because the graph I'm talking is weighted, but maybe I should have clarified better on that.

@Álvaro - sorry, I didn't realise this required a minimum reputation.

The question twice mentions "shortest path", and also "longer path", and only once mentions summing the weights. If you mean path of least total weight, you should edit your question to say that, instead of burying that here in the comments.

If we follow the algorithm, the following happens:
(1) Start at $a$. The distance from $a$ to $b$ and to $d$ are 2 and 1 respectively, so write $b=2$ and $d=1$
(2) From $b$ we can go to $c$ (meaning $c=2+3=5$) or to $e$ (meaning $e=2+1=3$)
From $d$ we can go to $e$ which will give $e$ the value $1+1=2$.
(3) At $e$, since $2<3$, we write $e=2$.
From $c$ we can now get to $z$ which (for now) will have value $z=5+2=7$
From $e$ (which currently has value 2) we can get to $z$ which means $z=2+2=4$.
Since $4<7$ we write $z=4$
(4) We are now at $z$, so the shortest path from $a$ to $z$ is 4.

You seem to miss the part that, as opposed to recursive search, you have to maintain a sorted list of all reached but not finished nodes and taking and processing the smallest one - and it can happen that the next node you will process does not have to be connected to the previous node you processed.
In your example, before processing $e$, you (assuming you didn't already process and thus exclude $b$) already processed $a$ and $d$ and your list is $[e=2,b=2]$.

So, now, you process $e$. Distance of $b$ stays 2 because from $b$ you are reaching it with distance 3, which is bigger. Then you add newly reached $z$ with distance 4 to the list. After that, your unfinished list looks like $[b=2,z=4]$.

$b$ is the next but that's actually not a problem at all as it will be shown next.

You process $b$ and you add $d$ to your list with distance 5 to your list, now being $[z=4,d=5]$

So, next you are processing $z$ even though you were last at $b$ that has no direct connection to $z$ and you are finished, finding your target. (if you were to evaluate all nodes, you would then proceed with $d$ and finish there, running out of new unfinished nodes )


